# Why does putting a variable inside an object.assign not work?

Tags: arrays, json, object, react-hooks, setstate

```
setPlayers(Object.assign([], players, {whichPlayer: {'points': players[whichPlayer].points+1, 'name': players[whichPlayer].name}}))
```

this line of code doesn't work for me, however if I put a number instead of 'whichPlayer' in one of the places it is used it starts working:

```
setPlayers(Object.assign([], players, {0: {'points': players[whichPlayer].points+1, 'name': players[whichPlayer].name}}))
```

Please help I've tried everything to solve this but there just isn't any information available that would help me with my problem.

https://github.com/baczek113/5_seconds Here is the link to the whole project if You need it(It's the first thing I've ever tried in react so please don't laugh at me XD)